# Juice UI: Publishing my web site - where have the controls gone?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, publishing, juice-ui

I've created a site using ASP.NET with Juice UI in Visual Studio 2012.  When I publish to my local machine's web server (Windows 7 64-bit, running IIS 7.5) everything behaves as it should.  However, when I publish to the company web server (Windows 2008 Server R2 64-bit, running IIS 7.5) the results are inconsistent.

90% of the time, when I browse the site the Juice UI controls are missing.  Yet when I check that the relevant files are on the web server, they all appear to be present and correct.

What could be causing this frustrating and intermittent problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory structure of the website different locally than on production? Could be a script location problem. Check the console output/error console in your browser to look for 404 errors when loading scripts.